# Dated folder batch file does not work on 20th of the month?

Tags: date, batch-file

I am new to this and have created a batch file that creates a current dated folder with a user entered title.
Unfortunately it does not create the year for the 20th of the month.
e.g. On the 19th it will create "140119 - Test" but on the 20th "0120 - Test"
Any ideas what is causing it?

It must be the Delims that is causing the issue but I don't know how to get around it.

```
@echo off
@REM Setups %date variable
@REM First parses day, month, and year into dd , mm, yyyy formats and then combines to be YYMMDD by removing the 20
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/20 " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yy=%%B
SET date=%yy%%mm%%dd%

call :inputbox "Please enter the folder name (Excl. Date):" "Standard Date folder"

exit /b

:InputBox
set input=
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do set input=%%a

if "%input%"=="" (exit /b)
mkdir "%date% - %input%"
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental issue is that the `delims=` phrase estalishes a **set** of delimiters, not a delimiter **string**. Any character between the `=` and `"` becomes a delimiter.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
REM Setups %date variable
REM First parses day, month, and year into dd , mm, yyyy formats and then combines to be YYMMDD by removing the 20
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ("%date%") DO ECHO A=+%%A+ B=+%%B+ C=+%%C+ D=+%%D+
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ("%date%") DO SET dd=%%B&SET mm=%%C&SET yyyy=%%D
SET yy=%yyyy:~-2%

SET xdate=%yy%%mm%%dd%
ECHO xdate=%xdate%

GOTO :EOF
```

`@echo off` turns off command-echoing. Having executed that instruction, there is no requirement for further `@instruction` commands. `@` simply turns off instruction-echoing for that one instruction.

You don't tell us what your date-format is, but I conclude that it's `dayname dd/mm/yyyy`. This is fundamental - personally, I use `dd/mm/yyyy` but many Overflowers would use `dayname mm-dd-yyyy`. Always a problem area - don't let's get started on *time*.

`%date%` is a magic variable, set by the system to potatoes according to the user's selected format-settings. Similarly, `%time%` is set to carrots. If you set a user-variable of the same name, then the user-variable overrides the system-set variable.

In the above, I've used `SET yy=%yyyy:~-2%`. To substring in batch, you need `SET var=%bigstringname:~start,length%` where `length` is optional and if missing means `the remainder of the string after`start`.`Start`may be 0 or positive meaning`this number of characters after the start of the string (or character-position, starting a position '0'). If negative, it means `this number of characters from the end of the string`.

Answer (score 0):

the result depends on your systems locale:

```
C:\Users\User\TEST>date /t
20/01/2014

C:\Users\User\TEST>for /f "tokens=1-3delims=/ " %a in ('date /t') do @echo(%c%b%a
20140120

C:\Users\User\TEST>for /f "tokens=1-3delims=/ " %a in ('date /t') do @set "mydate=%c%b%a"

C:\Users\User\TEST>echo %mydate%
20140120

C:\Users\User\TEST>set "mydate=%mydate:~2%"

C:\Users\User\TEST>echo %mydate%
140120
```

Please note the trailing space : `20/01/2014_`. You should not use system variables for local variables, ex `date`.

Comment: OK I see but how do I get the year to 2 digits. i.e. 140120 ?

Comment: @user3213256 enhanced my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if this is an option for you then this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher, using WMIC.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YY%%MM%%DD%"
```